# Represent a typedef defined in a C++ template class using UML

Tags: c++, templates, uml, generic-programming

I have a template class representing a UI widget. The class is called (surprisingly) `Widget`. The class defines `graphics_type` (via `typedef` or similar) which could be a `cairo_t`, a `HDC`, a `CDC*` or something similar. In other words, `Widget` defines a type called `graphics_type` which it uses for drawing stuff.

How do I represent the relationship between `Widget` and `graphics_type` using UML?

Bonus question: Do any C++ programmers here find UML useful in these situations?

Comment: Are you asking how to represent a `typedef` in a UML class diagram?

Comment: Not only that. This is a typedef defined as part of the public interface of a class. How do I represent the relationship between the two?

Comment: Add a note or comment. I have seen tools that had a `typedef` type of box `[<<typedef>>|name]`. I would probably use a `uses` relationship with a `<<typedef>>` annotation on the side... You can download and install BoUML (AFAIK it handled `typedef`s) and reverse engineer a small example to see what it generates.

Comment: @AgnelKurian a `typedef` is just a name substitution for another type, and is a C++ language feature. UML is supposed to be language-agnostic, it is supposed to omit any language-specific features altogether. That said, I'd use the original class (e.g. `HDC`), maybe add a short comment about the class being `typedef`ed, but no more. As for the relationship between the classes, just use the usual aggregation/composition (whatever fits your design).

Comment: I can certainly see benefit to being able to well represent a typedef. For instance, if you're typedefing a callback, you can't really represent that as a class, but it would still be nice to see visually: (`typedef int (*foo)(Bar*)`, where `foo` is the alias you're creating). I'd like to know if anyone has come up with a way to represent this. 

While I don't find UML a necessity all the time, when sketching out a nebulous algorithm, it's nice to play with a diagram before coding so you have some sort of blueprint.

Answer (score 3):

Sparx EA is linking typedefs to the aliased type via generalization. At least that is what happens when you import from source. The C++ generation template overrides Class if the stereotype is `<<typedef>>`. If the typedef is using a template, EA inserts:

```
typedef templateName<alias> alias;
```

Otherwise, it inserts:

```
typedef aliasedClass alias;
```

I went searching because I want:

```
typedef aliasedClass* class_ptr;
```

and I don't know how to express the pointer part in UML. I was hoping to find some standard way of expressing the construct but no luck.

Option 1: create a template that is just a pointer-maker:
    template  class _ptr { /* TMTFWIW */ }

Option 2: use a tag in my PIM-to-C++ PSM transform to insert the `*`.

I think I'll go with #2.

Answer (score 2):

publib.boulder.ibm.com has a great deal of documentation on many subjects, including quite a bit on UML.  Their rule for many C++-specific constructs, including typedef and others, is pretty much just as @David Rodriguez stated.

Answer (score 1):

Each has its own answer to the question of usefulness of UML. Maybe UML is good for very big projects, but I have nothing to say here.
In my practice I find it uneffective to develop code based on UML diagrams because class declaration in C++ is very informative and clear itself, especially if you define methods outside class body. Making aditional diagrams takes the same time but shows nothing new.

The second thing about class relation diagrams is that they are very good if built automatically from the existing code. Doxygen can do this for example. The plus is that you don't spend extra time for UML and can easily inspect current implementation. Also, making changes by hand on a printed paper with such а diagram is very handy for refactoring.

Comment: I use UML as a documentation tool. I don't generate code from the diagrams. I don't expect my diagrams to contain every detail of the structure, and I find the Doxygen output to be unwieldy. Instead, my diagrams are concise summaries of my design that I can show to my peers when trying to explain proposed hiearchies. It doesn't take a "very big" project to be useful; it just takes a non-expert audience (which includes some of my peers).  If you're not using UML to generate code, it's pretty easy to make useful diagrams quickly.

Comment: Hi @MikeC , 
It seems your experience with Doxygen is based on bad examples. Doxygen if being properly used can show only the most important information. You can easily separate and link parts of your documentation even if this logic is not reflected well in the code structure. You can omit unnecessary details and so on.